# Colored powder in a lens: will it need a cleaning?

Tags: lens, cleaning, maintenance

I was taking photos of people playing [Holi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holi). Some of the powdered colour landed on the lens of my Canon Powershot S95, and in the groove of the flash housing. By lens, I mean the cylindrical part that retracts, not the glass.

Does the housing of the lens have some protection that wipes the lens as it retracts (i.e, a self-cleaning mechanism)? Or will I need to give the camera to a professional repair shop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Hopefully you have wiped the stuff before turning the camera off,* otherwise there is probably some of it inside it.

There is nothing self-cleaning here and neither is this camera sealed against dust and particles from entering. It's a great camera you have, so I would bring it to Canon for a cleaning. They will take the camera apart and clean it. Here this service costs a bit over $100 CDN.

If you intend to exposur your camera to elements like this, it will quickly become expensive, so I recommend investing in a [weather-sealed](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?weatherproof=1&by=feature) or [waterproof](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?weatherproof=1&by=feature&waterproof=1) camera for those occasions. Unfortunately, there are very few such cameras with manual controls other than DSLRs which also require [weather-sealed lenses](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?weatherproof=1&by=feature) to be sealed.

Comment: I did wipe it off with a soft cloth or my finger, whichever convenient at that point of time. There was not a bunch of it, just a few particles here and there, but noticeable.

Comment: @Itai I'm afraid weather-sealed cameras seem to offer no protection against this particular type of dust. See https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-ruin-your-gear-in-5-minutes-without-water